# Android String.split() and/or StringTokenizer() not working in While loop

Tags: android, string, loops, split, token

This is very odd...

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("file")));
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] sa = s.split("a");
    String a = sa[0];
    String b = sa[1];
    String c = a + "the letter a was here" + b;
    // Do something with String c...
}
```

I get a force close at the line "String b = sa[1];".  java.lang.NullPointerException.
My 'String s' in the loop has multiple 'a' characters, that is not the issue.
'String a' is ALWAYS correct.
But 'String b' always throws the exception.
I declare the variables (sa, a, b, c) outside of the loop, no help.

THE ODD THING, StringTokenizer has the SAME EXACT PROBLEM.
It can only read the first token/split...

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "a");
int x = st.countTokens();
String a = st.nextToken();
String b = st.nextToken();
String c = a + "the letter a was here" + b;
// Do something with String c...
```

...inside the same While loop.
SAME EXACT PROBLEM!  'String a' is accurate, when the system gets to the 'String b' line, it throws the same exception/error/force close.
I even check the value of 'int x' just to make sure there are multiple tokens, and there are, again this is not the issue.

WHY in this While loop can I only access/read/assign/use the first split/token of my string that I have split/tokenized???

Comment: Can you try a different token instead of a maybe something like @ and let me know if it works

Comment: in the tokenizer, did you try using st.hasMoreToken() before assigning to b? that might be helpful.

Comment: Update with sample input, when I try your logic it is working fine.

Comment: **C.d.**:  Good idea, but I have tried many characters, same result.

**Urban**:  Always good practice, but I know the lines in the file, so I know how many tokes, so no need to check, and btw, it still returns true.

**thinksteep**:  I'm not surprised it works fine for you, it makes NO sense why it doesn't work.  A few lines of my file are:  "the man has a baseball", "the red car is fast and safe", etc...

I know there are multiple tokens, and the "st.countTokens();" returns 4 or 5 or however many (more than 2 always.)  I have NO IDEA why I can't 'access' the second token OR array :(

Comment: Ok, here is my very odd answer.  I deleted all of my code in this section, then copy and pasted what I posted here on SO, and it works now.  Don't know why, and currently don't care :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what ever reason, when having problems with "BufferedReader", I just uninstall the app from the test phone, and run from scratch, and the problem is fixed.  Possible the 'file' gets corrupted, I'm not sure.  I've run into this problem twice and uninstalling the app and re-running fixed it both times.